# Can I pass a State Hook as a prop to a component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Context: I'm fairly new to React so I may be going about this the wrong way, but I have a parent page with two components with different forms. I need the document id of the first form when submitted when it's complete to use in the second one. To do that I've tried placing the logic for both in the parent form, but to be able to hide the first form after it's been submitted, it's in a separate file and imported as a component

Anyway, to do this I'm trying to pass a State Hook like the following as a prop

```
const [zData, setzData] = useState({
    _id: uuidv4(),
    something: '',
    example: '',
  });
```

I can pass zData with no problem, but I can't pass setzData, I run into an error stating it's not a function. Is there any work around or other solution?

**Edit**
On the component I have this

```
<Part1 handleSubmit={handleSubmit} zData={zData} setzData={setzData} />
```

And on the other file its pretty much this

```
function Part1(handleSubmit, zData, setzData) {
return (<>

                <TextField
                  required
                  name="firstName"
                  label="First Name"
                  fullWidth
                  autoComplete="First name"
                  value={zData.firstname}
                  onChange={(e) => setzData({ ... zData, firstname: e.target.value })}
                />
</>);
}
```

Comment: `but I can't pass setzData` you should be able to. Can you show us the code you tried for that?

Comment: You can but it is better to wrap your set in another function and pass that function. Because passing a set function to children can cause lifecycle issues.

Comment: @NicholasTower Sure, I've added it

Comment: @DanysChalifour  Do you happen to have a resource for how to do that without running into the "React Hook "useState" is called in function ... which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function" error? (I get it even with useState imported, it only shows up in a separate function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function Part1(handleSubmit, zData, setzData) {
```

Props get passed to the component as a single parameter, not multiple. So what you've called `handleSubmit` is actually the props object, while the others are undefined.

You can either use a single parameter (probably rename it `props`), and access properties on it:

```
function Part1(props) {
  // ...
  value={props.zData.firstName}
  onChange={(e) => props.setzData(/*...*/)}
}
```

Or what you probably meant to do was to [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the object into local variables:

```
function Part1({ handleSubmit, zData, setzData }) {
```